# React router 4 nested route with params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having some difficulty understanding how to add a document route in the setup below with react router 4. Maybe the uuid needs to be passed as a prop to DocumentsPage such that you can return DocumentPage?

```
routes = {
    home: '/',
    documents: '/documents',
    createDocument: '/documents/create',
    document: '/document/:uuid',
}

<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path={routes.home} component={HomePage} />
            <Route path={routes.documents} component={DocumentsPage} />
            <Route path={routes.createDocument} component={CreateDocumentPage} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your route declarations there isn't one for /document (singular) - is that the problem?

Comment: There is not. Adding it has no effect. Looks like createDocument also points to documents. Hmm...

Comment: The createDocument route will therefore be unreachable as you have not specified 'exact'.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing off @mikkel's suggestion in the comments, try the following:

```
routes = {
  home: '/',
  documents: '/documents',
  createDocument: '/documents/create',
  document: '/document/:uuid',
};

<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={routes.home} component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path={routes.createDocument} component={CreateDocument} />
      <Route path={routes.document} component={Document} />
      <Route path={routes.documents} component={DocumentsPage} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In this case it will first look for an *exact* match for `/documents/create`, then `document/:uuid`, and finally `/documents`.

Getting the `uuid` in your `<Document />` component will be located in `this.props.match.params.uuid`.